# Is there an English metaphor/saying for this expression?

Tags: expressions, translation, metaphors, popular-refrains

I'm translating a book and the author has written down a saying that can be translated literally as "If you want to hit a dog you can easily/quickly find a stick" Like, if I wanted to hit a dog, finding something with which to hit it will be easy as I'll be looking for *anything* I can to injure it. It need not necessarily be a stick, but just some kind of weapon...

The meaning is if you're already predisposed towards hating something you'll quickly find a way to destroy it.

If nothing like this exists feel free to say that and I'll try and find a way around it. I'd rather not shoehorn in an awkward translation.

Comment: I'm no native speaker, but when I search for "it is easy to find a stick to beat a dog" I get quite a few results. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/it_is_easy_to_find_a_stick_to_beat_a_dog

Comment: Can you give the original plus a word for word translation? That might help with discovering a corresponding proverb if the exact one doesn't exist. Also the source author if one exists (like Aesop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This idiom does exist in English:

> it is easy to find a stick to beat a dog
>
> It is easy to attack (physically or verbally) a vulnerable person or thing. Primarily heard in UK.
>
> I know it is easy to find a stick to beat a dog, but you need to stop criticizing your son—he's not being malicious, he's just a child!

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/it+is+easy+to+find+a+stick+to+beat+a+dog

Comment: "Primarily heard in the UK"? Which part of the UK? I've never heard it.

Answer (score 0):

C.S. Lewis [wrote](https://apilgriminnarnia.com/2015/08/24/orwellthoughts/) about the relative merits of two books by George Orwell: Animal Farm and 1984. He suggested in this connection that there was little reason for all of the attention to sexuality in the latter book; anti-sexual hostility seemed to be just one more vice which the author could attach to the bad guys.

> But the principle that any stick is good enough to beat your villain
>   with is fatal in fiction. Many a promising ‘bad character’ … has been
>   spoiled by the addition of an inappropriate vice.

That saying seems similar an image similar to the one in your question. Lewis calls it a principle, perhaps suggesting that he considered it a familiar assumption. But it is not really a well-known saying today.